Nginx proxy pass for alias does not load font files
I try to set a page in WordPress as a standalone subdomain site by alias.
I found below link from stack and it indeed works for me for sub-domain reassignment

How to Alias a Page to a Sub-Domain

Below is my setting.
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name abc.example.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/abc$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;

    }
}

But, on the proxied subdomain, I cannot load font files properly. I've tried both local font files and Google remote font, but neither of them works.
I guess there is an issue with proxt header and firewall that disallows to call the font file when the domain name changes.
I've tried with simple html coded webpage w/ local font files, which indeed loaded font properly.
I believe it is somehow connected to WordPress's security setting, or insufficient proxy header setting that I don't know much of.
I've also tried location in the same server block, but font files are not loaded.

NGINX Proxy Pass

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;

    root /var/www/websites/example;
    
    location ^~ /abc/ {
      proxy_pass  https://abc.example.com;
      proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    }
}


Added below definition for font files in the same server block. Problem solved.
    location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 1M;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

